# binding itemsource of listview from viewmodel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

My ListView stays empty. 
What am I missing?

EDITED NEARLY ALL:
I created the JSON classes in my model.
I think my JSON is kinda wrong.

I want the json file which is stored on my webserver to be parsed into the listview using MVVM. For now there are just the two items I put in manually.

I would really appreciate some help.

viewmodel:

```
using KD_CHKLST.Models;
using KD_CHKLST.Utils;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KD_CHKLST.ViewModels
{
    public class AbfahrtskontrolleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Abfahrtskontrolle> items;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<Abfahrtskontrolle> Items
            {
                get { return items; }
                set
                {
                    items = value;
                }
            }



            public AbfahrtskontrolleViewModel()
            {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Abfahrtskontrolle>() {
                new Abfahrtskontrolle()
                {
                    text = "Frage 1",
                    description = "Description 1"
                },
                  new Abfahrtskontrolle()
                {
                    text = "Frage 2",
                    description = "Description 2"
                },

            };


            MyHTTP.GetAllNewsAsync(list =>
                 {
                     foreach (Abfahrtskontrolle item in list)
                     {
                         Items.Add(item);
                     }
                 });
            }
        }
    }
```

model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace KD_CHKLST.Models
{
    public class Abfahrtskontrolle
    {
        // JSON - Abfahrtskontrollfragen 
        public class Frage
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
        }
        public class RootObject
        {
            public IEnumerable<Frage> frage { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

my json file:

```
{
    "frage": [{
            "text": "Frage 1",
            "description": "Frage 1 Description"
        },      
        {
            "text": "Frage 2",
            "description": "Frage 2 Description"
        }
    ]
}
```

and finally my http class:

```
using KD_CHKLST.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KD_CHKLST.Utils
{
    public class MyHTTP
    {
        public static async Task GetAllNewsAsync(Action<IEnumerable<Abfahrtskontrolle>> action)
        {

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/chklst.json");

            Debug.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Abfahrtskontrolle>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                Debug.WriteLine(" hier ist meine geparste Liste: " + list);
                action(list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the viewmodel and somehow make it the data context of the ContentPage.

Comment: I instanciated the viewmodel in the xaml.cs `BindingContext = new AbfahrtskontrolleViewModel();` or what do you mean?

Comment: AbfahrtskontrollListe must be a public PROPERTY in order for it to be used in data binding

Comment: Jason is correct. You also have to spell the name of the property the same way in the XAML as in the C# file. C# AbfahrtskontrollListe  vs Abfahrtskontroll**e**Liste

Comment: so it is `public class AbfahrtskontrollListe
        {
            List<Frage> abfahrtskontrollListe { get; set; }
        }` ? now i cant set `abfahrtskontrollListe = rootObject.frage` in `GetJSON();`

Comment: changed my code on the base of [link](https://almirvuk.blogspot.de/2017/02/xamarinforms-listview-simple-mvvm.html). can you have a look again please?

Comment: Where is the PropertyChanged inside the setter of your binded property i.e Items?

Comment: @vahid missed it and added it. its not working tho. i guess it is the json function. it seems like no data is parsed into the obs-collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to change my model, my json and added the propertychangedevent to my Items. Now it is working!

My changed Model:

```
namespace KD_CHKLST.Models
{
    public class Abfahrtskontrolle
    {
        public int FrageID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My changed `ObservableCollection: Items` in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Abfahrtskontrolle> Items
            {
                get { return items; }
                set
                {
                    items = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Items)));
                }
            }
```

This works now because I edited my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "FrageID": 0,
    "Text": "text 1",
    "Description": "description 1"
  },
  {
    "FrageID": 1,
    "Text": "text 2",
    "Description": "description 2"
  }
]
```

Now it is working and I finally managed to bind data in a listview trough MVVM.
Thank you for your support.

-p